# Cannot step into function of QSortFilterProxyModel

Tags: c++, debugging, qt

I have a line in my code:

```
return QSortFilterProxyModel::data(proxyIndex,role);
```

Yet, when I press step into while debugging, this doesn't do anything, just skips this line. I'm in a debug mode, I have debugging symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few reasons why this could be happening:

- The debug symbols are out of sync with the binaries
- The source files location has changed and do not match the debug symbols
- The source files are different from when the module or debug info was buit
- The function is optimized out by the compiler
- The function is inlined by the compiler
- You don't have source files or pdb files for the actual function that is being called (QSortFilterProxyModel can be optimized to a different function as to not replicate code)